# Combining 2 Gradients

Tags: android, shader, gradient

I need to combine these 2 gradients.

```
LinearGradient val = new LinearGradient(
oval.centerX(),oval.bottom,
oval.centerX(),oval.top,
Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, 
Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

and

```
RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(
oval.centerX(),oval.centerY(),
oval.width()/2,
new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE , Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE } ,
null  ,
Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

I need an effect in which these two gradients are combined. How can I achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ComposeShader.

```
ComposeShader cs = new ComposeShader( linearGradient, radialGradient, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Comment: This is not working. I am getting the effect of the radialGradient only.

Comment: @user2520215: Try a different PorterDuff.Mode and see if there is one that shows you what you'd expect ...

Comment: Also what happens if you swap the linear and radial gradient shaders around in the compose shader?

Comment: On swapping them, linear gradient shows. I have tried other porter modes.

Comment: Both the gradients are overlapping each other, is it because of that?

Comment: @user2520215: Hmm.  Does calling "setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)" on your view fix the problem?

Comment: it's working for me, at least in case I need to combine 2 radialgradient